# SQL Developer : Holding Multiple values in Variable From Query Result

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help with query for sql developer.The requirement is a select statement which returns ID Column.I need to hold this ids in a variable and fetch the records associated with each id.Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you fetch the IDs you need into a PL/SQL variable? Why does this have to use a specific desktop application though? PL/SQL is portable :)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Your question lacks any specifics, please review [ask]. This outlines the expected minimum information you must provide for the community to provide a satisfactory answer. Your question lacks virtually all those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join statement.

for example:

select id from table_1 join table_2
on table_1.id = table_2.id;

Comment: I tried joins but there are 4 tables in chain like T1->T2->T3->T4,i need to use each  id to pull associated  child table records and each table has multiple ids.so,it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as far as I can tell.

But, if it is the same query all over again and you use its result (those ID values you mentioned) in another queries, then you could create a view

```
create or replace view v_id as
  select id 
  from some_table
  where some_conditions;
```

and then use that view as yet another data source, e.g.

```
select d.dname, e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  from emp e join v_id v on v.id = e.empno
             join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

or

```
select e.ename, e.job, e.sal
  from emp e
  where e.empno in (select v.id from v_id v);
```

or any other option you might choose.